# Understanding my loop code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Using sr As New StreamReader(strUsersPath)
        Dim line = sr.ReadLine
        Dim sline As String()
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            sline = line.Split("|")
            If sline(0) = tbUsername.Text And sline(1) = tbPassword.Text Then
                Form2.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                Exit Sub
            Else
                line = sr.ReadLine
                If sline(0) = tbUsername.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Invalid password!")
                End If
                If line = Nothing Then
                    MsgBox("Failed login")
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        End Using

End Sub
```

I have been trying to use this code for my login box, I have two textboxes, tbUsername and tbPassword, if the user clicks login then the code will open my users.txt file (in strUsersPath) and loop through until it finds a matching login. If the username is wrong it will give a messagebox ("Invalid password!") and if it does not find a username or password then it will give another ("failed login!").

However, my problem is that when I run the code, logging in works fine if the details are correct, if they are not however, both messageboxes come up, ("invalid password" + "failed login"), I know this is because the loop continues, but I can't seem to work out the syntax to do it how I want, any help?

Comment: You're not seriously storing passwords plain-text in a text file in a production app are you?

Comment: @Enigmativity Please point out in my post where I said it's for anything more than personal use. This is an activity I'm doing to learn, nothing has to be secure.

Comment: You didn't say to the contrary either. Just making sure that you weren't and to make sure readers don't think it's OK in a production system.

Comment: @Enigmativity I apologise, I didn't mean to be blunt. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to approach it:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Using sr As New StreamReader(strUsersPath)
        Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
        Do While Not IsNothing(line)
            If line.StartsWith(tbUsername.Text & "|") Then
                If line = tbUsername.Text & "|" & tbPassword.Text Then
                    Form2.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                Else
                    MsgBox("Invalid password!")
                End If
                Exit Sub
            End If
            line = sr.ReadLine
        Loop
    End Using
    MsgBox("Failed login")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run into a condition that would cause you to need to stop processing the file, then call Exit Do.  This will prevent the loop from going over your file completely if it already knows the answer (valid login or invalid password)

```
If sline(0) = tbUsername.Text Then
  MsgBox("Invalid password!")
  Exit Do
End If
```

Also, your second If condition is redundant.  The loop will end when line is nothing, so you can prevent checking that for each iteration and just put it after the loop.  The only way to get there is to have an invalid login.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Using sr As New StreamReader(strUsersPath)
        Dim line = sr.ReadLine
        Dim sline As String()
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            sline = line.Split("|")
            If sline(0) = tbUsername.Text And sline(1) = tbPassword.Text Then
                Form2.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                Exit Sub
            Else
                line = sr.ReadLine
                If sline(0) = tbUsername.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Invalid password!")
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        End Using
     MsgBox("Invalid Login")
End Sub
```

Lastly, I really hope that this is not a system that should actually be secure or anything, because looping of a plain text file for user logins that are not hashed or salted is not a very good method of securing your application.